# Doctrine 2 - iterate() - white screen error

Tags: php, symfony, loops, pdo, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get a lot of records from a database (about 30 000 results) with Symfony 2. In the Symfony there is a Doctrine database layer (Doctrine ORM & Doctrine DBAL). I would need to export these records into a Excel sheet file.
I tried to do this:

```
// $em is EntityManger
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT r FROM SystemBundle:RecipientWithStatistic r");
$iterableResult = $query->iterate();
// ... $iterableResult->next();
```

But I see a white screen.

When I tried to write:

```
echo "before query\n";
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT r FROM SystemBundle:RecipientWithStatistic r");
echo "before iterable\n";
$iterableResult = $query->iterate();
echo "before next\n";
// ... $iterableResult->next();
```

I saw in an output:

```
before query
before iterable
```

I would like to export (by any way) the data and write it into the Excel sheet. I know that in PHP exists PDO data layer, I tried earlier something like this and it worked:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT ...");
while ($row = $uresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row[...];
}
```

But what is the problem in the above solution is that I cannot use a plain PDO in the Symfony application.

Does anyone of you any suggestion how to read a large amount of the records?

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think you cannot use pdo in symfony 2?  Not that it would help.  Transferring 30K records in php is problematical at best.

Comment: does it work if you add a limit to your query and only select, say 10 rows?

Comment: I tried it. When I set max of result with the help of Query.setMaxResults(10), it works! I see "before next" text. So is there too many results? Is Doctrine not prepared for huge results?